# Signed in or Logged in callback for AWS Cognito service in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin. This is my first time using Kotlin. I am creating a log in form using AWS cognito service. For Kotlin, aws sdk only provide their own UI for logging in and signing up to Cognito service. This is my code

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this) {
            val signin = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(
                    this@LoginActivity,
                    SignInUI::class.java) as SignInUI
            signin.login(
                    this@LoginActivity,
                    MainActivity::class.java).execute()
        }.execute()
    }
}
```

But the problem is I need to do some tasks after user logged in or signed up. Is there a callback function I can implement?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way if you want to make your own custom UI for login. Simply create two text fields for username and password, and then get the text from those two fields storing them as Strings. After that, you simply call

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password, null, object : Callback<SignInResult> {
        override fun onResult(result: SignInResult) {
            // This means it succeeded
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            // This means there was an error (obviously)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
```

I also use this code to initialize an instance.

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(baseContext, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
        override fun onResult(userStateDetails: UserStateDetails) {
            Log.i("INIT", "onResult: " + userStateDetails.userState)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("INIT", "Initialization error.", e)
        }
    })
```

I found this to be much easier than using the terrible UI they provide in the SDK. This also isn't covered in the documentation, but should be since it is 10 times easier. To find more on this you can [look here.](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn)